# I am using ASP.NET MVC4 and i want to submit my two forms with single submit button, also i want to fetch data using form collection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am trying to build a Search filter and in this I have two forms. One is for basic search filter and another form is for more searches. In this I want that when the user clicks to more filters and click to see results both the forms will be submitted.

This is simple form having one input.

```
@using(Html.Beginform())
{
    <input type="text" name="input1" />
}
```

This is second form having another input and submit button.

```
@using(Html.Beginform())
{
    <input type="text" name="input2" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

I want that when the user clicks the `submit` button both the forms will be submitted and values of form will be fetched in controller using formCollection class.

Is this possible?

Comment: SO you want it that when you click a submit button, two forms get submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two submits would be processed as two separate POST commands, meaning that each `submit` would be handled by a separate thread in `.NET`, and they would be processed by two separate ActionMethod invocations.

Even if that would be the same ActionMethod, it will be invoked *twice*, and each one would not know about the other invocation or about its data.

The only way to achieve this is either by putting all data into **one FORM** (you could use e.g. an `<input type="hidden">` for that, with a value that you set using Javascript), or by doing at least one of the POSTs as an **AJAX Post** and then processing the results from the AJAX Post in a way that will achieve your end goal (about which you have not given us much information).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this over this way however you could do this by JQuery ajax,

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function()
 {   
     var Input1=$("#Input1").val();
     var Input2=$("#Input2").val();

    $('#btnsubmit').click(function () { 

    $.ajax({
        url: "ControllerName/Actionname",
        type: "POST",
        data: { InputValue1: Input1,InputValue2:Input2},
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
   });
 });` 

</script>
```

Then you can the values from controller action method.